# Create Objects using Cartesian product of provided fields

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

Suppose I have a class like this :

```java
class User{

   String name;
   String email;
   int age;
   Role[] role;
   // other fields.


   // constructors, getters , setters , ...

}
```

where "Role" is another defined class(or enum, does not matter).

now suppose I have a list of names, a list of ages, a list of list of roles(or a list of arrays of roles does not matter) , ...(other possible fields) and I want to create all possible combination of these fields to create all combination of users(Cartesian product of fields.)

```java
List<User> factory(Map<String , List> arguments){
   List<User> result = new ArrayList<>();

   // add all possible combination of created Users using "arguments" paramether.


   return result;
}
```

The problem is the number of provided arguments is not definite, for example, in a part of my app, I don't want to provide list of emails, so all created users have "null" email field.

how can I achieve proper results efficiently?(Is there any library or so on ?)
feel free to change input parameters or output of "factory" method if necessary.

P.s: We are developing an spring boot web application and we test our methods with Junit and Mockito. we want to test methods in different layers with a lot of data, but we don't want to harcode so many duplicate lines of code to generate samples. we want something like a "factory" method to generate all possible objects of a provided class with provided arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, the normal way to form the kind of Cartesian product you describe would be with a set of nested loops or an analogous shallow recursion.

> The problem is the number of provided arguments is not definite, for
> example, in a part of my app, I don't want to provide list of emails,
> so all created users have "null" email field.
>
> how can I achieve proper results efficiently?(Is there any library or
> so on ?) feel free to change input parameters or output of "factory"
> method if necessary.

Your alternatives depend a little on the details of `User`.  For example, what constructors does it have, or are you willing to give it?  Are (all) its fields modifiable after an instance is initialized?

One flexible approach that is adaptable to pretty much any specifics would involve a stateful factory class, something like this:

```
public class UserFactory {
   // Fields corresponding to those of User
   String name;
   String email;
   int age;
   Role[] role;
   // ...

   // constructor(s), maybe ...

   // setters ...

   /**
    * Instantiate and return a User with properties as presently configured on
    * this factory
    */
   public User createUser() {
       // ...
   }

   // ... see also below ...
}
```

Such a factory assists you in building up a set of properties for a `User` in a flexible manner, and it abstracts away the details of actually creating a `User` instance with the desired properties.

But if you are going to specify lists of property values via a map or similar, then you need a way to use the keys of that map to set factory (or `User`) properties.  For our purposes, it is convenient to put that on the factory class, and that has the additional benefit of keeping `User` cleaner:

```
   // in class UserFactory:

   /**
    * Sets the property of this factory specified by the given name to the
    * given value, which must be of an appropriate type.
    *
    * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the specified property name is not
    *         among the allowed property names
    *
    * @throws ClassCastException if the type of the specified value is not
    *         appropriate for the specified property
    */
   void setPropertyByName(String name, Object value) {
       // ...
   }
```

There are all sorts of ways you could implement that, but it is important to recognize that with that signature, it will necessarily rely on type-casting the value objects.  There are ways to wring type-safety out of something like this, but they would involve adding even more complexity to something that is already pretty complex for a test-support utility.  I don't think that's worthwhile.

Having that in place, the factory class is also a reasonable place to hang a method that generates the `User` lists you want, maybe something like this:

```
    // in class UserFactory:

    /**
     * Forms a Cartesian product of the property values given by the value lists
     * in the specified map.  Uses each of the resulting property sets together
     * with any other properties already set on the specified factory to create
     * a User, and returns a List of the resulting users.
     *
     * @param properties a Map from property names to lists of objects suitable
     *     for use as values of the designated property
     *
     * @param factory a UserFactory to use for User creation.  Any User
     *     properties whose values are not specified via the provided
     *     property map will take values as configured on this factory
     *
     * @return an unmodifiable List of User instances having combinations of
     *     property values drawn from the specified Map
     */
    static List<User> createUsers(Map<String, List<?>> properties,
            UserFactory factory) {
        // Extract the first property list, if any, ignoring any empty ones
        Optional<Map.Entry<String, List<?>>> firstEntry =
                properties.entrySet().stream()
                    .filter((x) -> !x.getValue().isEmpty())
                    .findFirst();

        if (firstEntry.isEmpty()) {
            // There are no (more) non-empty property lists.
            // Use the properties configured on the factory to create a single
            // User.
            return List.of(factory.createUser());
        } else {
            // Extract the selected property name, and form a Map containing the
            // properties other than the selected one.
            Map<String, List<?>> submap = new HashMap<>(properties);
            String propertyName = firstEntry.get().getKey();

            submap.remove(propertyName);

            // Set the selected property in the factory to each specified value
            // in turn, and generate User objects that can then be formed by the
            // factory with combinations of the remaining properties.
            return firstEntry.get().getValue().stream()
                    .flatMap((x) -> {
                            factory.setPropertyByName(propertyName, x);
                            return createUsers(submap, factory).stream();
                        })
                    .toList();
        }
    }
```

That uses recursion (one level per property name) combined with iteration over the property value lists to ultimately generate one `User` with each combination of property values.  If there are any properties not listed in the map passed to the top-level call, then the values of those properties set on the resulting `User`s will be determined by the provided `UserFactory` instance.

Do note, however:

- If the property lists contain duplicate values then you will get duplicate `User`s.  Perhaps a lot of them.  If you want to avoid the possibility of that, then you could consider adapting that to use `Set`s instead of `List`s for the properties, but that will help only for some types of property values (in particular, *not* for arrays).
- Inasmuch as you have at least one property whose value is an array, the above expects you to provide all the wanted *arrays* in the corresponding property value list -- not their individual elements.  There are various ways you could adapt to generating arrays of element combinations, too, which I leave as an exercise.
- Where any of the User properties take values of mutable type (arrays, for example, and maybe `Role`s or similar), you need either to make copies of those, probably in `UserFactory.createUser()`, or else accept that the `User` objects will have shared, mutable state.  The latter could easily set you up for unpleasant surprises.